# How to create windows service from jar file and how to call it from another jar file?

Tags: java, jar, java-service-wrapper

I have a jar file(primary jar) built for specific purpose. It gets data as input and stores output as certain format files. I have a another java app (secondary jar)built for secondary analysis with a user interface. Secondary jar uses primary jar for certain analysis.

Currently: The primary jar is initiated when secondary jar is started and stopped when secondary jar is closed. But i want to create primary jar as a service,so that it runs all the time and secondary jar just submits jobs to the primary jar service.

**Issue: I have searched and found ways to wrap jar file into windows services. But how to communicate with a running service from secondary jar app,sending data to it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few ways to communicate between java processes:

- old style RMI
- Socket
- shared file
- shared db

There are many ways, but you have to choose the one that is most appropriate for your problem.

Comment: So there is no direct ways to obtain instances(or calling) from the running jar service and submit data directly?

Comment: No there is no direct way, those are 2 separate processes that are not sharing anything.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JavaExe : it manages automatically those two processes (Service part and UI part) and their communication